# workbook.open Problems Macro Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I got problems in making the files search using workbooks.open. When the macro is executed, it shows runtime error "1004". Actually, I learn this from YouTube.
Can anyone know what's the problems?

This code actually find multiple excel files in one folder that we path.

```
Sub checkcopy()

Dim cf As String
Dim erow

cf = Dir("C:\Supplier\")

Do While Len(cf) > 0
MsgBox ("Check")
If cf = "SummaryCheckFile.xlsm" Then
Exit Sub
End If

MsgBox ("Check 1")

Workbooks.Open (cf)
Range("A1:E1").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))
checkFile = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

Sorry,

its show

*'go.xls' not found be found. Check The spelling of the file name and verify the file location is correct.
If you are trying to open the file from your list of mostly recently used files, make sure.....*

Comment: *it's show runtime error* means nothing unless you tell us what that runtime error is - you have it on your screen right in front of you, and there is absolutely no excuse for you to fail to include it in your question. While you're making the [edit] to add it, fix your question title so it explains the problem. Once you remove *Macro* and *Excel* (both of which are already in your tags), what's left is *workbook open problems* which is useless. Your title should explain the specific problem you're having or question you're asking in a way useful when seen in a search result by future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dir()` only returns the filename - it does not include the path, so you need to specify both of those when you call `Workbooks.Open()`

Also your loop will never exit (unless the first file is "SummaryCheckFile.xlsm") because all other calls to `Dir()` assign the return value to `checkFile`, so `cf` will never be cleared.

```
Sub checkcopy()

    Const FLDR As String = "C:\Supplier\"
    Const EXCLUDE_FILE As String = "SummaryCheckFile.xlsm"

    Dim cf As String, c As Range, wb As Workbook

    'set the first copy destination
    Set c = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    cf = Dir(FLDR & "*.xls*", vbNormal) 'only Excel files

    Do While Len(cf) > 0

        Debug.Print cf

        'opening this file ?
        If UCase(cf) <> UCase(EXCLUDE_FILE) Then

            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FLDR & cf, ReadOnly:=True)
            wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:E1").Copy c 'assumes copying from the first sheet
            Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)             'next destination row
            wb.Close False

        End If

        cf = Dir 'next file
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the path of `cf`, for example `cf = "c:\XXX\filename.xlsm"`, rather than `cf = "filename.xlsm"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with the parameter CorruptLoad when opening the xlsm which contains macros and causing runtime errors and no response.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks.Open ("enter your file path here"), CorruptLoad:=xlExtractData
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```